# An integration refrerring to Bessel Function and sinusoidal function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

The integral comes from a 2-D Fourier transform.
$$ \int_{0}^{\theta_0} \frac{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}J_{0}(a\sin(\theta))\mathrm{d}\theta $$
where
$$ a\in\mathbb R^+, \theta_0\in(0,\pi)  $$

I have drawn the function through numerical calculation as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm5Fx.png)

[image]

The parameters is set as follows: $$ a=[0,9.425] ,  θ_0=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
So the $x$-axis represents $a$, $y$-axis represents the integration result.

I want to obtain an analytical solution but I do really bad at solving the complex integration.

So can someone point a possible way to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/695196). Your question is missing context: Where does this integral come from? Why do you want to solve it? What have you tried? Why do you think there's a closed-form solution? Answering these questions gives other users a better idea of how to attack the problem or give you suggestions on how to proceed. Without adding additional info, your question will likely continue attracting downvotes or get closed, so I would encourage you to edit your question to add said missing info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Taylor expansion of the Bessel Function is
$$
J_0(a\sin\theta) =
1 
-\frac{1}{4} a^2\sin^2\theta
+\frac{1}{64} a^4\sin^4\theta
-\frac{1}{2304} a^6\sin^6\theta
+\cdots ;
$$
Interchange of the order of summation and integration yiels
$$
\int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta}{1+\cos\theta}J_0(a\sin \theta)d\theta
=
\int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta}{1+\cos\theta}[
1
-\frac{1}{4} a^2\sin^2\theta
+\frac{1}{64} a^4\sin^4\theta
-\frac{1}{2304} a^6\sin^6\theta
+\frac{1}{147456} a^8\sin^8\theta
+\cdots]
d\theta
$$
$$
=
-\int_1^{\cos\theta_0} \frac{x}{1+x}[
1
-\frac{1}{4} a^2(1-x^2)
+\frac{1}{64} a^4(1-x^2)^2
-\frac{1}{2304} a^6(1-x^2)^3
+\cdots]dx
$$
$$
=
\int_{\cos\theta_0}^1 x[
1 
-\frac{1}{4} a^2(1-x)
+\frac{1}{64} a^4(1-x^2)(1-x)
-\frac{1}{2304} a^6(1-x^2)^2(1-x)
+\cdots]dx
$$
and all these intermediate polynomials have trivial underivatives:
$$
\int x(1-x)(1-x^2)^k dx
=
\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l}(-1)^l\int x^{2l} x(1-x) dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l}(-1)^l\int  x^{2l+1} dx
-\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l}(-1)^l\int  x^{2l+2} dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l}\frac{(-)^l}{2l+2} x^{2l+2} 
-\sum_{l=0}^k \binom{k}{l} \frac{(-)^l}{2l+3} x^{2l+3}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this explicit and useful answer, I completely undestand it now.